# My Pictures in a Beamer file do not stay on the screen and I'm unsure why?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to create a Beamer file with some images alongside lists. However, when I insert my image it either does not appear or it shifts it half off the slide to the rigth - see below. My question is how do I move it into the white space above? I did try seperating the page into columns but had the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
\frame{
    \frametitle{Coordinate Systems}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Cartesian 
        \item Cylindrical 
        \item Spherical 
    \end{itemize}

\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{C:/Users/john/Documents/Uni/MMath/Major Project/Major Report/Python/Co-ordiantes/sphere_no_numbers.png}
\end{figure}

}
```

[image: My Image]

Comment: spaces in file names and paths cause problems, as well as _

Comment: You need to show us more code...

Comment: The path of your image causes a problem, thus the path and file name is erroneously written in fron of your image. If you fix this problem, the path will vanish and the image will be placed correctly. Don't try to fix this by changing the layout of the slide, fix the problem with the name.